# Rolify: Typical Usages of callback options:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I've searched the Web and Github and I see very few people using Rolify's callback options.

Rolify's callback options are (ref. https://github.com/EppO/rolify):

- before_add
- after_add
- before_remove
- after_remove

Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify :before_add => :before_add_method

  def before_add_method(role)
    # do something before it gets added
  end
end
```

What are the typical usages of Rolify's callback options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a personal experience, to  edit a field in the Users table after a role is added.

Having a web app and an api restricted to users with role :developer, after a user is assigned with that role I use the :after_add callback to create an access token for that user. You may need to remove the access token with :after_remove if the user isn't a :developer anymore.